# Запрос SQL срабатывает, хотя не должен

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE table
SET column = '123'
WHERE id = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table
    WHERE column = '123'
);
```

Запрос заключается в том, что он обновляет строку только в том случае, если в таблице нет строки в которой значение column равно тому значению, на которое мы хотим обновить строку. То есть у всех строк должно быть уникальное значение column.
Проблема в том, что этот запрос всегда срабатывает при любых обстоятельствах.
PS В моей СУБД нет UNIQUE так что не предлагать.

Comment: *В моей СУБД нет UNIQUE так что не предлагать.* И тем не менее назовите её, точно и включая версию.

Comment: CrateDB 5.5.1  .

Comment: Посмотрел документацию по их SQL-диалекту - скудно, не поможет совершенно. *запрос всегда срабатывает при любых обстоятельствах* Я верно понимаю, что 1) запись обновляется, даже если в таблице имеется запись с другим `id` и `column = '123'`? 2) Если убрать `WHERE id = 2` и оставить только `NOT EXISTS` - обновляются все записи таблицы?

Comment: Да, на оба вопроса.

Comment: *1) запись обновляется, даже если в таблице имеется запись с другим id и column = '123'? Да* И в то же время запрос `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE column = '123');` возвращает, как и должно, пустой набор записей при наличии записи с `column = '123'` и НЕпустой при отсутствии? Если да - можете смело писать багрепорт. И думать о смене СУБД.

Comment: На всякий случай... может, просто у этой СУБД не сделан нормальный error report? попробуйте запрос вот в такой форме: `UPDATE table SET column = '123' WHERE id = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE column = '123') x );`